# assign tshark output to variabels in script

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, packet-sniffers, tshark, sniffer

I am currently working on parsing pcap files that i have captured and decrypted with aircrack-ng.
I am looking into TCP-packages and i want to display them nicely with tshark-script.
Is it possible to replace numeric values with text in the tshark ouput?

Im also wondering if it is possible to assign tshark ouput to varibles in the script?

```
tshark -r readfile.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e data -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysis.out_of_orders
```

The output is the following:

```
 number| time    |   data/payload | 1/NULL (retransmission) | 1/NUL(out 
  23        48.151077           
  24        48.151028                      1
  25        48.152101           
  26        48.152052                      1    
  27        48.154661           
  28        48.155124                      1    
  29        48.163865  0002303030303030     
  30        48.164404                      1    
  31        48.168025  0003303030303030
```

But i would like to present the output like:

```
number | time    | data/payload   | RETRANS | Out_of_order
 23     48.151077           
 24     48.151028                   RETRANS 
 25     48.152101           
 26     48.152052                   RETRANS 
 27     48.154661           
 28     48.155124                   RETRANS 
 29     48.163865  0002303030303030     
 30     48.164404                   RETRANS 
 31     48.168025  0003303030303030
```

on the left you have the packet number and timestamp from the pcap file.
The bytes 00023030303... is sniffed packets that have been sent between a client and server (1 to 100). The singel bytes is the tcp flags.

Answer (score 0):

Piping `stdout` of your call to the program `tr` is one way to achieve this:

```
tshark -r readfile.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e data -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysis.out_of_orders | tr '1/NULL (retransmission)' 'RETRANS' | tr '1/NULL (out of order)' 'Out_of_order'
```

Comment: Hey! thank you for your response! Is this for assigning variables or the terminal output?

Comment: for the output. To be honest I did not get the variable assignment part of the question.

Comment: Okay! Im gonna update the question with more material. I want to assign for example the "tcp.analysis.retransmisson" filter. When the filter recognize the flag it outputs a 1 to the terminal and a blank/NULL when not triggered.